# Why does the UK produce so many research papers?

Tags: publications

I was taking a look at [Scimago Journal & Country Rank](https://www.scimagojr.com/countryrank.php).

[image]

Is there any specific reason why UK produces way more research paper than that of Germany and Japan?

**Note.** kindly, don't bring up futile arguments like population doesn't really matter in case of research paper publication (e.g. India), etc.

Comment: For starters, check out which journals are indexed in this, and in which language they publish. (Also, the UK's population is hardly "much smaller" than Germany...65M vs 82M)

Comment: I can't give a particuarly substantive answer, but I will say that Britain has a strong tradition of scientific research and in university league tables it is second only to the United States - of course, how much credence you give league tables is your decision.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, so chinese people are publishing more english papers than germans/japanese do? also, how about japan't population?

Comment: @FourOhFour, which means germany/japan do not have tradition of strong scientific research.

Comment: @yahoo.com they both do, of course, but I would argue that the UK's is the strongest. I don't know, but it might be the case that Germany is still suffering from the effects of having a very considerable number of its eminent scientists flee the Nazi regime and settle in other countries.

Comment: @yahoo.com Your question seems to massively contradict itself, for what it's worth: "....even though UK's population is much lower? Note. kindly, don't bring up futile arguments like population....". So you raise the issue of population, but also consider it irrelevant. What exactly is your point?

Comment: I would really love to see historical figures from before WWII. It would look very different.

Comment: @yahoo.com what percentage of each population is in the publishing range ?

Comment: Indeed @Thomas I read somewhere that prior to WWII, the main language for chemistry publications was German, not English.

Comment: Before Hitler, German universities were considered among the best. I don't think they've ever recovered.

Comment: "Showing off" is very much accepted in the US or UK, while generally frowned upon in say France (or Germany for that matter). From this point of view, "bragging" is much more accepted in the UK. There are many contemporary papers that leave one underwhelmed as a reader, wondering why this was even published. Add to that, the good papers are also very easily drowned out by all the noise. Then add in the "diploma mill" "research groups" which you can also find at Russel Group universities...

Comment: @yahoo.com ?? Germany and Japan have indeed a strong tradition of research. However in Germany (same as in France), the really good research takes place at research institutes (under the umbrella of the Max Planck Gesellschaft, Helmholtz Gesellschaft or privately run, Fraunhofer) while the main taks of universities is to educate. - In the UK, universities are run as a commercial entity (though they are registered as a charity) and research funding tends to be quite lucrative for getting attention which brings in paying foreign students.

Comment: @DetlevCM as if that is not case in germany?

Comment: @SSimon, nope. that is not the case in Germany.

Comment: @DetlevCM,this is the fundamental reason. you can put your comment in an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: @DetlevCM hard to believe, I dont agree that German universities are bad in publishing and reaserch, I will go futher much and tell that they are one of the nbest in europe

Comment: @SSimon where do you think they said German universities are bad at publishing and research? I don't see anything like that in any of their comments.

Comment: @SSimon I never said they are bad at research. I said it isn't their main job. German universities exist to teach, not to produce a globally recognised "brand" through lots of research papers. You can have what is effectively a "village university" in Germany with a small research group that is internationally recognised due to the contacts of the professor leading the group. - The really good research is carried out at research institutes. Incidentally, PhD students at these institutes will often have a second association with a university which acts as the degree granting institution.

Comment: @ChrisH I appologize it was refered to the detlevcm comment, but I find German universites more realible and fair for reaserch.

Comment: @DetlevCM I agree that institutes have more fundings, but I wouldnt disregard reaserch on German universities. Yes ,you are right, but isnt this the case for UK? Insitutes and university merge?

Comment: @SSimon The UK does not have research institutes in a traditional sense. You may have "setups" in the university that are called "Institute" but they are a part of the university and effectively just another department. Something like the Max Planck Gesellschaft, Helmholtz Gesellschaft or CNRS just does not exist in the UK (or US for that matter). - Universities in the UK also do contract work for industry. Its hard to get cheaper labour than a PhD student (about 13000 pounds per year plus feed of about 3000-4000 Pounds per year...)

Comment: @yahoo.com I wrote a more extensive answer post for you and for others to peruse.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but a complex and nuanced one. I do not think that comments or answers of somebody's on-the-spot hypothesis will be helpful, and would suggest looking for academic work on the topic; I feel sure there will be some.

Comment: I wish there were similar data for US states.  On the one hand, there’d be a clear signal from population and wealth, but you’d also see some anomalies.  I’d love to know how California stacks up to the UK (half the population, but a strong tradition of great universities).  I expect the answer to be that in any large economy one expects some regions to be the leaders in any particular business, for universities in Europe that happens to be the UK (and Switzerland, which is even better per capita).

Comment: I don't have any data to back this, so I'm adding as a comment instead of an answer but there are two hypothesis I can think: a) if most journals are in English, it would be easier for an English-speaking population to generate content; b) the British Empire was the bigger colonial power, so many people from the former colonies (specially India, with a population higher than 1 billion) studied in UK or have some relationship with UK universities

Comment: Could it be something like.. hmmm.. most publishers are british?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is very common for academics to not live and work in the country of their birth, and I would assume that this becomes the more common the more research active they are. Many of the publications from British universities will not have been written by British (born) scientists.

Instead, we see stable loops of the following type:

University X has a good reputation
-> Productive researchers move to X
  -> a lot research gets done and published at X
    -> the reputation of X is good

The UK is home to many very prestigious universities, is not subject to language barriers and has mostly avoided historical disruptions to its research activity.

Comment: +1, but also remember the role of funding, which has been reasonably consistent over a long time.

Comment: So the answer to the question would be "Because it has a disproportionately high number of good Universities" ?

Comment: Does the UK have a higher % of residents with PhDs than other countries?

Answer (score 31):

Many possible factors, but one that we can prove is that **the UK has a disproportionate number of the best universities.**

[The Times Higher Education World Universities list](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2018/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats) states that the US has 110 of the 200 best universities worldwide, while the UK has 31, Germany has 20, and China has 7. Of course, this definition of "best" will invite lots of controversy, and will not only be based on research metrics -- but it does not seem impossible that the UK has the second-highest number of excellent universities worldwide. With this many excellent universities, we would expect a correspondingly high number of papers.

*Why* the UK has so many excellent universities is a different question for which it is harder to come up with hard evidence, though the first-mover advantage that @Arno suggests seems plausible. Excellent universities have an easier time attracting excellent researchers, so it's a vicious cycle.

One corollary: why does China rank so high with only 7 excellent universities? Well, in one sense they don't, China has ~20x more people than the UK. But beyond that, not all papers come from universities, and the Chinese government is investing very heavily in R&D.

Comment: One should perhaps note a disclaimer that Times Higher Education comes out of the UK, and thus may be somewhat biased towards the UK and the west.

Comment: Best by what measure? Have you ever encountered UK students? The UK's education is so great, that they have to import a large proportion of their PhD students and academics... - Then ranking include research papers, while non US/UK countries carry out research at research institutes. Look at the nature ranking for research by institution, you will find that CNRS suddenly ranks very highly (they are French).

Comment: @DetlevCM I'm not contradicting or confirming your assessments of quality, but they're perhaps less relevant to the claims in the answer. UK universities could still be "excellent" (on someone's measures of output) and have people working there who do good research, without this implying that the education in the universities (or the strength of the UG students) is good

Comment: @YemonChoi If you want to say that good research groups exist in the UK, then yes, they do. As in any other country too.

Comment: @DetlevCM I just meant to say that your remark "The UK's education is so great, that they have to import a large proportion of their PhD students and academics" - which is shared by several of my friends and fellow UK academics - is not really relevant to cag51's claims. And I used to work outside the UK, and I know people who work in France and in Gemany, so yes, I am aware that the THE tables are, erm, disputable

Comment: @YemonChoi I guess it is a rather snarky remark, but let me explain where it comes from: An education systems primary task is to educate the population and nowadays also foster the exchange of people and ideas. If the education system, which includes the universities, is good, one would expect a large number of "local" PhD students. - Again, bringing in people from the outside is great because it brings in new ideas. (One criticisms of the French system of Grand Ecoles is that is leads to 'groupthink' with managers obtaining the same education from the same schools.)

Comment: @YemonChoi But if a large number of academics must be "imported" to fill the "gap" in academia, it points to serious deficiencies in the educational system. A system that can only thrive by importing academics cannot be described as good - no matter  how well it compares in any ranking. And while rankings are often very research focussed, it is the education that is overall more important as it sets the foundations for the future.

Comment: @DetlevCM thanks. FWIW I actually agree with your misgivings but once again, I think we are veering away from the original question at hand, namely "Why does the UK produce so many research papers"

Comment: I believe this is begging the question. These universities are highly ranked to a large degree _because_ of their research output. Arguing that their research output is high because they're highly ranked is therefore circular.

Comment: China drops below both the UK and Germany when ranked by citations, rather than documents: https://www.scimagojr.com/countryrank.php?order=ci&ord=desc When ranked by citations per document the US, the UK, and China all drop considerably (China especially so): https://www.scimagojr.com/countryrank.php?order=cd&ord=desc

Answer (score 17):

Transforming comments into an anaswer:

One large difference between the UK/US and say Germany and France is that"showing off" is very much accepted in the US or UK, while generally frowned upon in say France (or Germany for that matter).

Having fully embraced the "publish or perish" dogma in the UK (I will guess most applies to the US too, but I have lived in the UK) means that there is a desire to produce as much "output" as possible to create a recognised brand, which hopefully attracts more research funding and international, fee paying students. 
This has become particularly clear in the UK in recent times, with an excessive focus on rankings for academic and their work, be it h-indices, "impact factors" and whatever they have come up with lately. (There is a new metric of some sort that one university uses.)
This of course ignores the fact that research often needs time to be appreciated and utilised.

In part, such visibility can be achieved by employing lots of PhD students - and even large "Russel Group" universities are not immune to effectively becoming diploma mills, at least on the level of individual research groups.

Where the system comes full circle, is in the way that research funding is awarded: Often applicants for grants can benefit from showing a large publication record which again promotes the publication of quantity over quality. The simplest visible effect of this 'world view' is the splitting of large bodies of work into individual research papers rather than publishing a single comprehensive piece of work. Since two papers will, to the administration, look better than one.

Another difference between the UK as well as US and say Germany as well as France is the "job description" of universities.
The primary task of a university in Germany of France is to teach - to educate teachers and to train/develop future researchers (or managers/leaders in the system of the French Grand Ecoles).
Research takes place at research institutes which can be private or public.
Examples of such research groups are for Germany the Max Planck Gesellschaft, Helmholtz Gesellschaft of Fraunhofer. In France we have CNRS but also the CEA.

In contrast, the UK universities, though registered as charities, very much operate like commercial entities.
(For those in search of some controversy, an article about the pay of vice chancellors in the UK: https://www.theguardian.com/education/2018/mar/11/university-vice-chancellors-are-paid-far-more-than-public-sector-peers )
In addition, there is a certain desire amongst politicians to reduce state support for universities - one of the reason for the rise in tuition feeds from 3000 pounds per annum to 9000 a few years ago (around 2011/2012 I think).
As a result, universities are required to provide as much income as possible through their own means. In the grand scheme of things universities have three main avenues to sustain funding: 1) tuition fees, overseas students pay especially well, 2) public research grants 3) industry research funding.
Some institutions also have access to 4) trusts set up by former students who became wealthy or funds collected through donations.

Points 1 to 3 require public visibility of the university, be it to attract students or to justify why they should be funded through work. The easiest way to obtain such visibility is through papers - which in turn encourages the publication of more papers.

Comment: This is the answer many people (including OP) want to hear, but it is not correct.

Comment: @Thomas I hadn’t even thought of this but upon reflection I think that this is in fact a very large part of the full answer (in addition to what Arno wrote).

Comment: This answer can be summarized as "they publish more because they're vain bean counters". Of course, that's what you want to hear if you dislike the UK, but the reality is that there is also a disproportionate amount of high-quality research coming from the UK.

Comment: Along the lines of @Thomas ’s comment, this answer seems to be contradicted by the h-index and (to a lesser extent) the citations per document numbers. If the primary reason for the UK’s high research output was that the work is low quality, they wouldn’t have the second highest h-index. Obviously bibliometrics aren’t everything, but it’s hard to look at this data and say that most UK publications are junk in my mind.

Comment: China has the most concerning numbers in this regard, though that’s at least partially explained by that many researchers don’t speak Chinese

Comment: I think that the UK is probably one of the countries where the cultural bias *against* "showing off" is strongest. No data here, just a long association with some UK researchers.

Comment: *"showing off" is very much accepted in the US or UK* Wait, what? In the UK I know, ever since a child can speak it is pretty much ingrained in them that showing off is crass. Don't take me wrong, but having reading that line I found myself doubting everything you wrote after it, as it seems rather biased.

Comment: This is heavy on narrative and light on evidence. I call [Citation Needed].

Comment: @DividedByZero I'm not sure when you lived in the UK, but it cannot have been recently. Do not compare the UK of 30-40+ years ago with the UK today.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Indices unfortunately tell you nothing. A paper can be cited a lot because it is bad or because it is good. Comprehensive work can be split into multiple papers which then cite each other because they depend on each other. - Neither of these actions are inherently dishonest, but will skew indices. Such measures also do not work across subjects. Some people talk about journals with an impact factor of 10 or more. Well, for computational chemistry, the best are around 3. The absolute numbers mean very little in the end.

Comment: @DetlevCM I live in the UK, and have all my life. In my experience the attitudes toward "showing off" vary somewhat based on geographical area, class lines, style of upbringing, and a whole mess of other things, but I wouldn't describe it as "very much accepted", at least not universally. Of course, it depends what you mean by "showing off"; I'll grant that there isn't the cultural norm of extreme humiity, keeping your head down, andot drawing attention, but the reverse isn't entirely true either. Either way, your answer would be improved by some supporting evidence for its key elements.

Comment: @anaximander Try living in a different country then for a change. You should notice quite a difference - and with that I mean live, not just visit over a holiday.

Comment: It's very simple - the UK has seven of the top 50 universities in the world, with very strong research departments.  That's why more papers are produced.

Comment: @DetlevCM I live in the UK now, and have lived here for the last four years. Prior to that I lived in France. I am not comparing the UK of "30-40+ years ago" to that of today, I'm comparing the UK of today to the France of four years ago.

Comment: @DividedByZero And you don't find France much more reserved and humble overall? - I definitely do. (Incidentally, I nowadays live in France since having left the UK in 2016 after about 9.5 years.)

Comment: @DetlevCM No, I certainly don't, but if you do that's your opinion. And I have no objection to you sharing your opinion, but I disapprove of the manner in which you have done so in your answer. Opinions should be shared as opinions, not facts.

Answer (score 12):

**We speak English**

A very big factor, and one not mentioned in any answer, is that the British are native English speakers. Since English is, overwhelmingly, the language in which science is published in (thanks America!), native English speakers have a significant advantage in writing papers and getting them accepted.

It's also a big advantage in attracting good scientists from other countries because they already speak the native language. Whereas when I moved to Germany I needed to start learning German, a German PhD moving to the UK for their PostDoc would already speak the local language because they needed it to publish, read research, and present their findings. This makes both living in the country, and the teaching side of the job easier and more accessible. Learning languages is hard, and takes a lot of time, so already knowing the language is a big advantage. This helps the UK maintain long standing network advantages.

Comment: india? canada? australia? south africa?

Comment: @yahoo.com Few very people in India speak English at a C1 level. You’ll see that Canada and India both show up on the top 10 list you posted. Only one country can be #3, and I’m sure that Canada also does disproportionately well due to their linguistic advantage. Yes, there are other factors involved but I am sure that Jack is right that this is a big one.

Comment: @yahoo.com Australia and Canada do produce impressively large amount of research for their size, while India and South Africa are really not comparable to the UK because they're not first world countries and are much less rich.

Comment: .... New Zealand?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add a few points to Arno's answer. This is data from Scimago system, which has been largely run and maintained by the US, UK, and, well, Netherlands where it is based. Countries like India, China, former Soviet Union, etc. have their own systems where their researchers produce massive amount of publications. They are of substandard quality of course because they are hedged from global competition by local bureaucracies and/or language barriers. I'm not sure about India, but China has recently passed regulations that their researchers need to publish at least one paper in Scimago or Web of Science indexed journal to get a PhD and certain academic positions. So expect an uptick there soon, but not great. There are headwinds for non-English speaking countries obviously because of the network effect of English language in science and business. But both Scimago and Web of Science continuously add journals from non-English speaking countries to their rankings.

Comment: The UK/west also produces a lot of substandard noise. - The problem of low quality publications is not unique to the non-English world.

Comment: @DetlevCM that is very true. And I think this problem is getting worse with the number of publications doubling every several years, but the number of readers not. But you wouldn't believe the scale of it in developing countries where it seems like there are more writers of scientific papers than readers and barely any quality control, other than formatting requirements.